# Irreducible projective representations of $\mathbb{Z}_2\times\mathbb{Z}_2$

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-groups, representation-theory

I am currently learning about projective representations of finite groups and their reducibility. According to Schur's theorem (Schur 1904) the degree (dimension) of each irreducible projective representation of $G$ over $\mathbb{C}$ divides $|G|$.

> Now how can one construct irreducible projective representations of $\mathbb{Z}_2\times\mathbb{Z}_2$?

I am not mathematician and I am new in this topic, so any reference about projective representations with practical applications in physics would be appreciated.